# Is it possible to get listed registered email accounts on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

There is a form in my App, and I want to make it easier to user to fill out the form. Can I get the registered email accounts on Email App and ask user to choose one to use for my form?

Answer (score 2):

You can set auto-correction to "on" and the keyboard type to "email" in the text view properties. In this case when the user begins to type his email address the system offers its own address as an auto-correction tooltip. That's all what you can do with this.

Comment: It seems like this method has been changed in new versions. I doesn't seem work on iOS 6.3.